# Microsoft Access 2010 tables not showing the new record row with the asterisk

Tags: microsoft-access-2010

I have an .accdb on the network. The .accdb has various objects (queries, tables, forms).

The problem lies in a form which has the following dependency

```
form <--- table <---- query <---- other tables/queries.
```

So the form has a table (in table layout), where some column are dropdown/list from a query.

I want to work through the form to edit the table in table layout. Normally, the layout provides a "new record row (*)" in the last row and I can edit that row to insert a new record into the table.

But with no change in form and table settings, about 10% of the time when I open the .accdb, the "new record row" is not there. No amount of closing the application and opening it will show the row. I can edit all the existing records, no problems. Giving up and waiting for a new day, or if lucky, several hours sometimes work.

Question: What can cause the "new record row" to go missing? How to make it show?

**EDIT:** I found that the table has a table property dialog which has an option "Read Only When Disconnected -- Yes/No". But when I set it to "No", it reverts to "Yes" itself again. Furthermore, I copied the .accdb from the network to the desktop it still has the problem.

This [thread](http://newsgroups.derkeiler.com/Archive/Comp/comp.databases.ms-access/2009-12/msg00011.html) talks about a offline/online mode in Access 2010. But I can't seem to google for more information.

Any ideas?

Comment: @Gnoupi lol.. yes, didn't notice I was thinking of Asterix. haha.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After 2 months, I finally found the answer to this mystery.

A table can be in "Cannot add new record" mode if it is in sorted mode.

Clearing the sort can be tricky, and the best way to do it is to go (Access 2010) to the ribbon > Home > "Sort & Filter" group > Remove Sort.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, it just don't show up! However, the record gets added. Do the following:

- Click column header down arrow
- Click text filters
- Click contains
- Input the values you inserted and click OK
- You will find the row in which the record is inserted

This happens because the column data is not sorted, as said by @Jake. I believe we do not need to unsort the data. The method I suggest can be helpful to verify if the data is inserted or not.